# Ti-84+CE Reverse Polish Notation Progam

Tags: c, embedded

A few weeks ago, I wrote a Reverse Polish Notation program for my Ti-84+CE calculator. It was a successor to a program I wrote in TI-BASIC a while back, but since that one had too much input lag to be usable, I decided to write this one in C and compile it to native z80 assembly.

I wrote this program the night before a competition I intended to use it in (in fact, I put the finishing touches on it literally moments before starting the exam itself!), so keep in mind that I was on a time crunch so I wasn't going for the cleanest possible codebase. Still, as I'm not very experienced with C, I'd like to know what sort of improvements I could make to the code.

Here is a demo GIF of the program being used to find the answer of a sample number cruncher question:

[image]

I published a git repository with the program at https://github.com/arjvik/RPN-Ti84

This is the code:

```c
#include <tice.h>

real_t stack[99];
char buffer[50];
uint8_t idx;
bool decimal;
bool negative;
bool constantsmode = false;
bool scimode = true;
bool radians = true;
real_t decimalfactor;

real_t r_0, r_1, r_2, r_3, r_4, r_5, r_6, r_7, r_8, r_9, r_10, r_ln10, r_pi, r_e;

void init_real_constants() {
    r_0  = os_Int24ToReal(0);
    r_1  = os_Int24ToReal(1);
    r_2  = os_Int24ToReal(2);
    r_3  = os_Int24ToReal(3);
    r_4  = os_Int24ToReal(4);
    r_5  = os_Int24ToReal(5);
    r_6  = os_Int24ToReal(6);
    r_7  = os_Int24ToReal(7);
    r_8  = os_Int24ToReal(8);
    r_9  = os_Int24ToReal(9);
    r_10 = os_Int24ToReal(10);
    r_ln10 = os_FloatToReal(2.30258509299);
    r_pi   = os_FloatToReal(3.14159265359);
    r_e    = os_FloatToReal(2.71828182846);
}

void draw_line_clear(bool clear) {
    os_RealToStr(buffer, &stack[idx], 0, 1, -1);
    if (clear) {
        os_SetCursorPos(9, 0);
        os_PutStrFull("               ");
    }
    os_SetCursorPos(9, 0);
    os_PutStrFull(buffer);
}

#define OVERDRAW_IS_REDRAW 0
#if OVERDRAW_IS_REDRAW
void draw_line() {
    draw_line_clear(true);
}
#else
void draw_line() {
    draw_line_clear(false);
}
#endif

void drawdecimal_line() {
    os_SetCursorPos(9, 0);
    os_PutStrFull(buffer);
    os_PutStrFull(".");
}

void draw_stack_clear(uint8_t row, bool clear) {
    if (row >= 9) {
        os_SetCursorPos(8, 0);
        os_PutStrFull("...            ");
        real_t len = os_Int24ToReal((int24_t) idx);
        os_RealToStr(buffer, &len, 0, 1, -1);
        os_SetCursorPos(8, 4);
        os_PutStrFull(buffer);
    } else {
        if (scimode) {
            os_RealToStr(buffer, &stack[row], 0, 2, 2);
        } else {
            os_RealToStr(buffer, &stack[row], 0, 1, -1);
        }
        if (clear) {
            os_SetCursorPos(row, 0);
            os_PutStrFull("               ");
        }
        os_SetCursorPos(row, 0);
        os_PutStrFull(buffer);
    }
}

void draw_stack(uint8_t row) {
    draw_stack_clear(row, false);
}

void draw_full_stack() {
    for (uint8_t row = 0; row < idx && row <= 9; row++)
        draw_stack_clear(row, true);
}

void delete_stack(uint8_t row) {
    if (row < 9) {
        os_SetCursorPos(row, 0);
        os_PutStrFull("               ");
    }
}

void new_entry() {
    decimal = false;
    negative = false;
    stack[idx] = r_0;
    draw_line_clear(true);

}

void new_problem() {
    idx = 0;
    os_ClrHome();
    buffer[0] = 0;
    constantsmode = false;
    new_entry();
}

#define BINARY_OP(os_func)                                              \
do {                                                                    \
    if (os_RealCompare(&stack[idx], &r_0) != 0) {                       \
        if (idx >= 1) {                                                 \
            stack[idx-1] = os_func(&stack[idx-1], &stack[idx]);         \
            draw_stack_clear(idx-1, true);                              \
            new_entry();                                                \
        }                                                               \
    } else {                                                            \
        if (idx >= 2) {                                                 \
            stack[idx-2] = os_func(&stack[idx-2], &stack[idx-1]);       \
            draw_stack_clear(idx-2, true);                              \
            delete_stack(idx-1);                                        \
            idx--;                                                      \
            new_entry();                                                \
        }                                                               \
    }                                                                   \
} while (false);

#define UNARY_OP(os_func)                                               \
do {                                                                    \
    if (os_RealCompare(&stack[idx], &r_0) != 0) {                       \
        stack[idx] = os_func(&stack[idx]);                              \
        draw_line_clear(true);                                          \
    } else {                                                            \
        if (idx >= 1) {                                                 \
            stack[idx-1] = os_func(&stack[idx-1]);                      \
            draw_stack_clear(idx-1, true);                              \
            new_entry();                                                \
        }                                                               \
    }                                                                   \
} while (false);

#define REAL_TRIG(name, os_func)                                        \
real_t name(real_t *a) {                                                \
    real_t t;                                                           \
    if (radians)                                                        \
        t = *a;                                                         \
    else                                                                \
        t = os_RealDegToRad(a);                                         \
    return os_func(&t);                                                 \
}

REAL_TRIG(degRadSin, os_RealSinRad)
REAL_TRIG(degRadCos, os_RealCosRad)
REAL_TRIG(degRadTan, os_RealTanRad)

#define REAL_INVTRIG(name, os_func)                                     \
real_t name(real_t *a) {                                                \
    real_t t = os_func(a);                                              \
    if (!radians)                                                       \
        t = os_RealRadToDeg(&t);                                        \
    return t;                                                           \
}

REAL_INVTRIG(radDegAsin, os_RealAsinRad)
REAL_INVTRIG(radDegAcos, os_RealAcosRad)
REAL_INVTRIG(radDegAtan, os_RealAtanRad)

real_t realLogBase10(real_t *a) {
    real_t t = os_RealLog(a);
    return os_RealDiv(&t, &r_ln10);
}

real_t realSquare(real_t *a) {
    return os_RealMul(a, a);
}

void main() {
    uint8_t key;
    
    init_real_constants();
    new_problem();
    
    while ((key = os_GetCSC()) != sk_Graph) {
        if (constantsmode) {
            if (key == sk_Power) {
                stack[idx] = r_pi;
                constantsmode = false;
                draw_line_clear(true);
            } else if (key == sk_Div) {
                stack[idx] = r_e;
                constantsmode = false;
                draw_line_clear(true);
            } else if (key == sk_2nd) {
                constantsmode = false;
            } else if (key == sk_Del) {
                new_problem();
            }
        } else {
            if (key == sk_0 || key == sk_1 || key == sk_2 || key == sk_3 || key == sk_4 ||
                key == sk_5 || key == sk_6 || key == sk_7 || key == sk_8 || key == sk_9 ) {
                if (!decimal) {
                    stack[idx] = os_RealMul(&stack[idx], &r_10);
                    real_t toAdd = r_0;
                    if (key == sk_1) toAdd = r_1;
                    if (key == sk_2) toAdd = r_2;
                    if (key == sk_3) toAdd = r_3;
                    if (key == sk_4) toAdd = r_4;
                    if (key == sk_5) toAdd = r_5;
                    if (key == sk_6) toAdd = r_6;
                    if (key == sk_7) toAdd = r_7;
                    if (key == sk_8) toAdd = r_8;
                    if (key == sk_9) toAdd = r_9;
                    if (!negative)
                        stack[idx] = os_RealAdd(&stack[idx], &toAdd);
                    else
                        stack[idx] = os_RealSub(&stack[idx], &toAdd);
                    draw_line();
                } else {
                    real_t toAdd = r_0;
                    if (key == sk_1) toAdd = r_1;
                    if (key == sk_2) toAdd = r_2;
                    if (key == sk_3) toAdd = r_3;
                    if (key == sk_4) toAdd = r_4;
                    if (key == sk_5) toAdd = r_5;
                    if (key == sk_6) toAdd = r_6;
                    if (key == sk_7) toAdd = r_7;
                    if (key == sk_8) toAdd = r_8;
                    if (key == sk_9) toAdd = r_9;
                    toAdd = os_RealMul(&toAdd, &decimalfactor);
                    if (!negative)
                        stack[idx] = os_RealAdd(&stack[idx], &toAdd);
                    else
                        stack[idx] = os_RealSub(&stack[idx], &toAdd);
                    decimalfactor = os_RealDiv(&decimalfactor, &r_10);
                        
                    draw_line_clear(true);
                }
            } else if (key == sk_Chs) {
                stack[idx] = os_RealNeg(&stack[idx]);
                negative = !negative;
                draw_line_clear(true);
            } else if (key == sk_DecPnt) {
                if (!decimal) {
                    decimal = true;
                    decimalfactor = os_RealDiv(&r_1, &r_10);
                    drawdecimal_line();
                }
            } else if (key == sk_Clear) {
                new_entry();
            } else if (key == sk_Left) {
                if (negative) os_RealNeg(&stack[idx]);
                if (!decimal) {
                    stack[idx] = os_RealDiv(&stack[idx], &r_10);
                } else decimal = false;
                stack[idx] = os_RealFloor(&stack[idx]);
                if (negative) os_RealNeg(&stack[idx]);
                draw_line_clear(true);
            } else if (key == sk_Enter) {
                if (idx == 98) {
                    new_problem();
                } else {
                    draw_stack(idx++);
                    new_entry();
                }
            } else if (key == sk_Mode) {
                scimode = !scimode;
                draw_full_stack();
            } else if (key == sk_Stat) {
                radians = !radians;
                os_SetCursorPos(9, 0);
                os_PutStrFull(radians ? "r" : "d");
            }else if (key == sk_Del) {
                new_problem();
            } else if (key == sk_Add) {
                BINARY_OP(os_RealAdd);
            } else if (key == sk_Sub) {
                BINARY_OP(os_RealSub);
            } else if (key == sk_Mul) {
                BINARY_OP(os_RealMul);
            } else if (key == sk_Div) {
                BINARY_OP(os_RealDiv);
            } else if (key == sk_Power) {
                BINARY_OP(os_RealPow);
            } else if (key == sk_Log) {
                UNARY_OP(realLogBase10);
            } else if (key == sk_Ln) {
                UNARY_OP(os_RealLog);
            } else if (key == sk_Sin) {
                UNARY_OP(degRadSin);
            } else if (key == sk_Cos) {
                UNARY_OP(degRadCos);
            } else if (key == sk_Tan) {
                UNARY_OP(degRadTan);
            } else if (key == sk_Apps) {
                UNARY_OP(radDegAsin);
            } else if (key == sk_Prgm) {
                UNARY_OP(radDegAcos);
            } else if (key == sk_Vars) {
                UNARY_OP(radDegAtan);
            } else if (key == sk_Square) {
                UNARY_OP(realSquare);
            } else if (key == sk_Recip) {
                UNARY_OP(os_RealInv);
            } else if (key == sk_2nd) {
                constantsmode = true;
            } else if (key == sk_Yequ) {
                os_ClrHome();
                os_SetCursorPos(0, 0);
                os_PutStrFull("Arjun's RPN Calculator");
                os_SetCursorPos(1, 0);
                os_PutStrFull("v2.0 (ASM)");
                os_SetCursorPos(3, 0);
                os_PutStrFull("git.io/ti84rpn");
                while (os_GetCSC() == 0);
                os_ClrHome();
                draw_full_stack();
                draw_line_clear(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `tice.h` I used is from [CE-Programming/toolchain](https://github.com/CE-Programming/toolchain/blob/master/src/ce/tice.h)

Comment: I'm more curious about how you made that gif! Is there now a way to run and/or screencap TI-83 programs too?

Comment: @Quuxplusone I actually ran the program in an emulator to record the GIF. The specific emulator I used was [CEmu](https://github.com/CE-Programming/CEmu), but there are tons of other emulators available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
#define OVERDRAW_IS_REDRAW 0
#if OVERDRAW_IS_REDRAW
void draw_line() {
    draw_line_clear(true);
}
#else
void draw_line() {
    draw_line_clear(false);
}
#endif
```

why not

```
#define OVERDRAW_IS_REDRAW false

void draw_line() {
    draw_line_clear(OVERDRAW_IS_REDRAW);
}
```

?

Otherwise: I'm not clear on the capabilities of your z80 compiler, but

> compile it to native z80 assembly

is probably not what's going on. You're probably compiling to native z80 *machine code* and care more about this machine code than the assembly. Depending on your compiler it could emit an assembly listing as an intermediary step; in `gcc` this would be something like `gcc -Wa,-al`.

`BINARY_OP` and `UNARY_OP` are a little awkward. They're going to balloon the size of your `main` which is already too large. Instead consider converting them to plain-old functions that accept a function pointer for `os_func`. Among other things this will cut down on your final binary size. It's doubtful that the call overhead will be so burdensome as to be noticeable, but test it.

I see your `while (false)` pattern reflected as well in the third-party toolchain header you're using. Why? If you just want a block, which is reasonable, keep the `{}` and drop the `do/while(false)`. Anonymous scoped blocks are easy and free in C, and should not need a loop hack. But again, if you convert your `_OP` functions to normal functions this will be a non-issue.

`main` is too big and complex. Break it down into subroutines.

This whole block:

```
                if (key == sk_1) toAdd = r_1;
                if (key == sk_2) toAdd = r_2;
                if (key == sk_3) toAdd = r_3;
                if (key == sk_4) toAdd = r_4;
                if (key == sk_5) toAdd = r_5;
                if (key == sk_6) toAdd = r_6;
                if (key == sk_7) toAdd = r_7;
                if (key == sk_8) toAdd = r_8;
                if (key == sk_9) toAdd = r_9;
```

can be replaced with a lookup table. Some maniac decided that the `sk_` values should be non-contiguous:

```
#define sk_0                0x21
#define sk_1                0x22
#define sk_4                0x23
#define sk_7                0x24
#define sk_2                0x1A
#define sk_5                0x1B
#define sk_8                0x1C
#define sk_3                0x12
#define sk_6                0x13
#define sk_9                0x14
```

so if you do make such a lookup table, it will have an "interesting" value order; you could initialize it like

```
static real_t r_numerals[sk_9 - sk_0 + 1];

// ...

r_numerals[sk_0 - sk_0] = r_0;
r_numerals[sk_1 - sk_0] = r_1;
r_numerals[sk_2 - sk_0] = r_2;
r_numerals[sk_3 - sk_0] = r_3;
r_numerals[sk_4 - sk_0] = r_4;
r_numerals[sk_5 - sk_0] = r_5;
r_numerals[sk_6 - sk_0] = r_6;
r_numerals[sk_7 - sk_0] = r_7;
r_numerals[sk_8 - sk_0] = r_8;
r_numerals[sk_9 - sk_0] = r_9;

// ...

toAdd = r_numerals[key - sk_0];
```

or if you're more worried about performance and less worried about memory, just make an array that's 0x40 elements long and represents the entire key space. You could take this a step further and have a complete lookup table populated with pointers to your own functions, which would really cut down on the key-checking noise in `main`.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I agree with all the improvements you have suggested so far.

With respect to the assembly vs machine code point, I believe you are right. The Ti84+ toolchain seems to mix up the two terms, potentially because the Ti84+ operating system calls compiled programs "ASM programs" (as opposed to interpreted "BASIC programs").

Comment: The tips on using function pointers seem especially handy. I agree that replacing the macro-generated blocks with a function taking a function pointer would be a big size improvement at a very little performance hit. Replacing the long if-else chains with function pointer lookup tables also seems like a great idea.

Comment: The `do { } while (false);` macro pattern was picked up from a bunch of places recommending its use. Among them are the Linux kernel formatting guide and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-use-apparently-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-macros). Why do these places recommend this pattern when a regular block is allowed?

Comment: I don't think they recommend such a block, but attempt to justify why a developer may have preferred it: as an awkward replacement of `break` instead of `goto` (which you don't need), or out of misplaced compiler compatibility concerns.